# I want to select the dynamic cell and autofill it till the last row

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

the value is in cell C and lastrow2 and want to autofill till lastrow3

```
Range("C" & lastrow2).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(.Cells(lastrow2, 3), .Cells(lastrow3, 3)).FillDown
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to `AutoFill` and `FillDown` in the same line? `FillDown` is out of place on a `Range` that is the `Destination` parameter of `AutoFill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `.Select` and then `Autofill`, you can populate the entire range in one go. Is this what you are trying?

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastrow2, 3), ws.Cells(lastrow3, 3)).Formula = _
ws.Cells(lastrow2, 3).Formula
```

Where `ws` is your relevant sheet. For example

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1
```