# Autofill excel from text boxes and fields from work sheet column entries VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, data-entry

I need to create a macro that can take data in columns F through I and autofill it down to the last cell in column E that has data in it. The code below almost does what I need it to do. However, I want to be able to use this macro with different data further down in columns F:I. How can i do this?

```
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Range("e" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim x(1 To 4) As Variant
```

Next

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
x(1) = Range("f2")
x(2) = Range("g2")
x(3) = Range("H2")
x(4) = Range("I2")

.Range("F3:i3").Formula = x
.Range("f3:i" & lastrow).FillDown
End With
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67626913/i-want-to-select-the-dynamic-cell-and-autofill-it-till-the-last-row